# What will happen to the previous memory of allocated objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I have an array with some values i.e allocated some memory.
What will happen to the previous memory if i will alloc new memory for the array.

```
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:anObject, nil];

self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:anObject2, nil];
```

What will happen to memory of objet `anObject`, Will it be preserve in memory or it will automatic remove from memory after allocating new memory ?

Comment: I wonder if both lines, when written in this sequence, will be optimized by the compiler in a way that only the second assignment is executed.

Comment: Pretty basic question. Are you using ARC or MRR?  Do you have a custom setter method for `self.array`?  Did you bother reading *any* of the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The object on your first array, `@"1"` is actually a pointer to an `NSString` object.
Once the pointer is released by overriding the value in your array, the memory the `NSString` instance occupied will be deallocated. The new string object (`@"2"`) is not neccessarily stored in the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

On allocating memory second time previous data will be lost like 
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2", nil]; on doing this objects from previous memory location 
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", nil];
will no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

> What will happen to memory of objet anObject, Will it be preserve in memory or it will automatic remove from memory after allocating new memory?

It is impossible to answer this question definitively as it depends on other factors which are unknown.

What I think you are trying to understand is the memory ownership model of arrays (`NSArray`, `NSMutableArray). In the hope this guess is correct:

First think in terms of *ownership*. An object is created by its first owner, can over its lifetime have multiple owners, and will die sometime after it has no owners. Under ARC ownership is handle for you in combination with attributes such as *strong* and *weak*. Under MRC ownership is manual using methods such as `retain` and `release`.

Arrays, and dictionaries, sets, etc., use the model:

- When an item is added to the collection ownership is taken for that item.

  - When an item is removed from the collection ownership is relinquished.
  - When a collection itself becomes unowned it relinquishes ownership of all the items it contains.

So in your particular case what happens to `anObject` depends at least on:

- Whether the first `NSMutableArray` has other owners.
- Whether `anObject` itself has other owners.

There are also objects which are effectively owned by the application, so they never appear to die (they die when the app terminates). A common immortal object is a string literal, so if `anObject` is a string it may well live on.

HTH